# Pick up particular lines from a text file and calculate them together

Tags: macos, applescript

This might be quite a long shot, but I've written an AppleScript for myself that keeps log on how long I work for whatever project. I'd like to create another script that calculates the overall spent time based on the info from a log file.

Generally my log files look like this:

```
140304 1353 - Start
140304 1459 - End
work time :     0106
break time :    0000

140307 1248 - Start
140307 1353 - End
work time :     0105
break time :    0000

140321 1101 - Start
140321 1306 - Have a break now
140321 1342 - Back to work
140321 1423 - Have a break now - Go eat
140321 1522 - Back to work
140321 1522 - End
work time :     0246
break time :    0135
```

So I would need to get every "work time" value and calculate them together.

I've tried googling around this, but I'm not sure how to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applescript's Text Item Delimiters (TIDs) are perfect for this. We just break the text up into a list by setting TIDs to the text just before the number you want to grab, in this case "work time". Then I just grab the next word after the TIDs because that's the number. So it's easy. The result of your example is 457. My script returns the sum plus shows all the values used to calculate the sum: {457, {"0106", "0105", "0246"}}

```applescript
set workLog to "140304 1353 - Start
140304 1459 - End
work time :     0106
break time :    0000

140307 1248 - Start
140307 1353 - End
work time :     0105
break time :    0000

140321 1101 - Start
140321 1306 - Have a break now
140321 1342 - Back to work
140321 1423 - Have a break now - Go eat
140321 1522 - Back to work
140321 1522 - End
work time :     0246
break time :    0135"

set beforeText to "work time"

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to beforeText
set textItems to text items of workLog
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

set theSum to 0
set sumItems to {}
repeat with i from 2 to count of textItems
    set workTime to word 1 of (item i of textItems)
    set end of sumItems to workTime
    set theSum to theSum + (workTime as number)
end repeat

return {theSum, sumItems}
```

Now just replace the first line in my code with this and it will work for you on your log file. Good luck.

```
set workLog to read (choose file)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! Actually I'm familiar with TIDs, but for some reason I couldn't come up with this answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `do shell script`-based alternative to @regulus6633's pure AppleScript answer:

Note: I'm not sure what your work-time numbers such as `0106` represent - here I'm simply assuming that they are decimal integers to be summed.

```applescript
set logFile to "/Users/jdoe/hours.log" # Replace with POSIX path to your log file
set total to do shell script ¬
   "awk '/^work time :/ { total+=$4 } END { print total }' " ¬
   & quoted form of logFile
```

The shell command uses `awk`, which greatly simplifies parsing.